# Ruby Cucumber says path can't find route when Rake Routes show it is there

Tags: ruby, path, routes, cucumber, rake

I have Ruby on Rails with Cucumber. The db has been migrated for the test environment and I can see it using sqliteman. The problem is that while rake routes shows the routes I want, cucumber returns an error saysing the routes don't exist.

Routes are:

```
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

Then, in the same prompt box, I run "bundle exec cucumber" and get this error in two different scenarios in the same feature file:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

The features/support/paths.rb file fails on the two lines where *movie_path* and *edit_movie_path* are called

```
when /^the details page for (.*)/
  mov= Movie.find_by_title($1)
  movie_path(mov)
when /^the edit page for (.*)/
  mov= Movie.find_by_title($1)
  edit_movie_path(mov)
```

Was I supposed to rake routes into the test environment somehow? I'm not sure what I'm missing as it "looks" like all the pieces are there.

Comment: Is `mov` actually what you expect? Or is it `nil`?

Comment: I commented out or deleted lines to narrow down the scope of the test and the test is apparently still seeing the whole/unedited file. How am I supposed to run the tests so the edits take affect?

Comment: Uhhh, there's no reason it wouldn't use the test file you have unless you didn't save it or edited the wrong file.

Comment: Good catch Andrew. Yes it is nil.

Comment: Added an answer with a way to make this easier to figure out in the future `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

This will works like this:

```
when /the edit page for "(.*)"/
    movie= Movie.find_by_title($1)
    edit_movie_path(movie)
```

But you can also use this:

```
   when /the edit page/
        edit_movie_path(Movie.first)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `Movie.find_by_title($1)` isn't finding anything like you expect, while results in `mov` being `nil`, and thus it can't find a route to it since there is no ID.

You can make this more obvious by adding a `!` to `find_by_title` so it raises an exception when nothing was found:

```
when /^the details page for (.*)$/
  movie = Movie.find_by_title!($1)
  edit_movie_path(mov)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
```

The `{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}` here refers to the `controller` and `action` related to this route. But you would need the `:id` parameter to properly create the path to  this route.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
```

The `{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}` here refers to the options given when trying to create the path for the route.

I would ensure your `mov` is not nil and returning a proper `Movie` record.